# If P = NP, then the following problem would be solvable in polynomial time?

Tags: algorithms, computational-complexity

The problem is the following (searching a database with no structure):

There exists a function $f$, that maps a bitstring $z$ to a binary value. There is only one marked element $x$, such that $f(x) = 1$. For all other inputs $y \neq x$ it holds that $f(y) = 0$. The goal is to find the input $x$.

The function $f$ is a blackbox / oracle: its implementation in terms of logic gates, for example, is not known and each evaluation of $f$ (call to the oracle) takes a constant amount of time.

This problem can then be casted into a decision variant. Given a solution $x$ to the problem, it can be checked in constant amount of time, simply by evaluation of $f(x)$.

Guessing the inputs will take exponential time. So this "algorithm" is in NP.

Would P = NP imply that there is a classical algorithm on a Turing machine, that solves this problem in polynomial time? Can't it be quite easily proved that there exists no polynomial algorithm here? (Time complexity being polynomial in the number of input bits)

Comment: Hi, I edited your question with MathJax! Definitely consider using it for next time to make the question more readable for the potential answerers on the forum!

Comment: Isn't this algorithm the same as a linear search? Why would that require any more than polynomial time? Is it because a bitstring of length $n$ has $2^n$ possible values, so you are implying that a linear search will take time $\mathcal{O}(2^n)$? To me the crux is how you are quantifying the "size" of the input - perhaps it is more natural to consider the scaling with the number of possible inputs.

Comment: I guess before answering this question, we run into the following problem. If $f$ is a black box we can't access except by evaluating $f$ in constant time, then presumably it can't be part of the input (because we can do whatever we want with the input). So what *is* the input to this problem? If there's no input, then it doesn't make sense to ask "does this algorithm run in time polynomial in the size of the input".

Answer (score 3):

First of all, remember that an *individual* instance of a problem isn't in $P$ or $NP$; rather, we talk about the complexity of a (parametrized) *family* of problems. For instance, $9\times 9$ Sudoku is in $P$; in fact, it's solvable in constant time! The constant may be large, but that's irrelevant. Instead, we have to talk about the complexity of Sudoku with respect to the board size. So you can't just have a 'single' bit string; rather, you need to have (at least one) bit string for every input length.

Putting that aside, even if you *do* assume that there's one bit string of each length that returns true, your problem still isn't in $NP$; this time, the issue goes the other direction. Remember that $NP$ means verifiable in polynomial time by a *Turing Machine*. You cannot simply treat $f$ as a black box; it must be represented in some fashion. If you want to try and obscure it, then you have to treat it as an [oracle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_machine), and the problem you've constructed is in $NP^f$ — nondeterministic polynomial time with an oracle for $f$. Similarly, a deterministic polynomial-time algorithm would be in $P^f$. But there are already well known to be oracles $f$ for which the question 'goes either way'; there are oracles for which provably $P^f=NP^f$ (for instance, if $f$ is 'sufficiently strong' that its query power overwhelms $P$ and $NP$; I believe taking $f$ to be a Turing-complete set such as the set of all strings on which a particular Universal Turing Machine halts works here) and those for which provably $P^f\neq NP^f$ (in fact, if we choose a 'random' oracle $f$, then $P^f\neq NP^f$ with probability $1$).

Comment: Fair enough. What if $f$ would be a logic circuit? Easy to implement, and for a given input $y$, $f(y)$ can be computed in polynomial time. However the exact input-output relation is not known, similar to a hash function.

Comment: @Hans-UlrichRudel The implementation details of $f$ only matter if they're given as input to the problem. If you want to say '$f$ is a logic circuit' then you have to say _what_ logic circuit; otherwise it's still a black box.

Comment: This is becoming a different problem than the initial one. If one would come up with an extension to the SHA-1 hashing function, that generalizes to input bitstrings of arbitrary length $n$, then this is a circuit whose details are known. Instead of having a binary output, $f$ outputs a bitstring, one of which corresponds to "1", all others to "0". (the chosen output bitstring would be a parameter of the problem). $f$ can then be computed in polynomial time on a Turing machine. But the best classical algorithm finding the marked element is still exponential (if $f$ is a one-way function)

Answer (score 1):

If $A$ is any algorithm making at most $q$ queries to the blackbox $f$, $A$  is going to observe $q$ items of $f$.  Since there are in total $2^n$ items, $q$ should be at least $2^n-1$, at the worst case.  (After observing $2^n-1$ items, $A$ can definitely find $x$ without error.  On the other hand, if $q<2^n-1$, then there is definite possibility of error.)

This argument holds whether P=NP or not.

More concretely, assume that $A$ is a deterministic algorithm making $q<2^n-1$ queries.  Let $x_1, x_2, \dots$ be the sequence of queries $A$ makes, and let $y_1, y_2, \dots$ be the sequence of corresponding responses that $A$ gets.  Then, $x_1$ doesn't depend on anything (except on the 'code' of $A$ itself), and $x_2$ depends on $y_1$, and $x_3$ depends on $y_2$, and in fact also on $y_1$ as well.  In that way, eventually $x_i$ depends on $y_1, \dots, y_{i-1}$.

Now, fix any such algorithm $A$, and fix the response sequence $y_1, y_2, \dots, y_{2^n-2}$ to be all zero: $y_1=y_2=\dots=y_{2^n-2}=0$.  This will completely determine the query sequence $x_1, \dots, x_{q}$.  Now, there are at least two points which $A$ hasn't queried so far, and let us denote them as $x'_0$ and $x'_1$.  We define two functions $f_0$ and $f_1$ as follows: both $f_0$ and $f_1$ respect the query sequence: $f_b (x_i)=0$ for all $b=0, 1$, and $i=1, \dots, q$.  And then, set $f_0(x_0')=1, f_0(x_1')=0$, $f_1(x'_0)=0, f_1(x'_1)=1$.  We can see that, since both $f_0$ and $f_1$ respect the query sequence, when $A$ interacts with either $f_0$ or $f_1$, it is guaranteed that $A$ will precisely ask queries $x_1, \dots, x_q$, and completely miss $x'_0$ and $x'_1$.  Now, after the queries, $A$ will output its answer.  Since $A$ is deterministic, its answer also depends on the response sequence $y_1, y_2, \dots, y_q$ (as well as the code of $A$).  In any case, it is deterministic, so its answer will be something fixed, say $z$.  If $z\neq x'_0$, then this means that $A$ errs when interacting with $f_0$.  On the other hand, if $z=x'_0$, then this means that $A$ errs when interacting with $f_1$.

This adversary argument essentially forces $A$ to have worst cases each time and eventually to lose: the responses $y_i$ are adversarially chosen to deny $A$ any useful information, as much as possible.

Comment: Your argument actually tries to show that this problem is not in P, but isn't correct. Specifically "On the other hand, if q<2n−1, then there is definite possibility of error." cannot be formally proved yet (else NP != P).

Comment: @Kaind: when $q<2^n-1$, then there are at least two possible values, say $x_1$ and $x_2$ that the algorithm hasn't seen both $f(x_1)$ and $f(x_2)$.  Since the access to $f$ is completely black-box, and since $A$ hasn't seen $f(x_1)$ and $f(x_2)$, both cases of $f(x_1)=1$ and $f(x_2)=1$ are still possible and the algorithm cannot eliminate either possibilities reliably.  In this situation it is impossible that the algorithm can reliably pick the right answer.

Comment: This isn't correct. "Since the access to f is completely black-box" - in this statement you are assuming that the set of strings oracled is chosen at random - but this is not true. What you must show is that there isn't a smart deterministic algorithm to find a set of strings which does not contain the true string.

Comment: @Kaind: no I'm not, and I'm not making any outrageous new claim.  This is a standard argument often known as the 'adversary argument'.  Actually, it doesn't matter whether the oracle is randomly chosen or just 'given' (via the universal quantifier), or, it doesn't matter whether the algorithm is deterministic or probabilistic.  Oh well, I will update my answer, spelling out the whole details.

Comment: THanks for the explanation. +1.